# How to find ClientId of a control in prototype javascript

Tags: javascript

I have HTML control in my page .Could you please tell me  how to get client Id using prototype javascript.

Comment: I'm assuming this is ASP.NET.  Could you provide us with code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: I have a div in my page Id of div changes every time as i am making Ajax calls I need to access this div id through javascript...

Answer (score 0):

Give your div a class name that doesn't change between ajax calls and get a reference to the div through the class name. I'm a jquery user, but I'm assuming that you could do the same thing using prototype.